# JSON How to search keys name value and print the objects that contains a string or set of strings with case insensitivity?

Tags: json, output, jq, data-objects

Goal:

- Search the keys actual name value for a string or set of strings
- search using case insensitive values
- return the object(s) containing the values

Un-sanitized test data:

```
{
    "PassworD": "dashnd8",
    "Name": "Katy"
}
{
    "PasSWOrd": "DJNAS98das98",
    "Name": "Paulo"
}
{
    "Pa$$word": "H(AD*Sn",
    "Name": "Crissy"
    
}
{
    "PW": "nA(*DS",
    "Name": "Jamel"
    
}
{
    "pW": "0d9asm0i",
    "Name": "Denny"
}
```

sanitized test data:

```
{
    "Password": "PW",
    "Name": "Katy"
}
{
    "Password": "pW",
    "Name": "Paulo"
}
{
    "Password": "pw",
    "Name": "Crissy"
    
}
{
    "Password": "passWorD",
    "Name": "Jamel"
    
}
{
    "Password": "PAssword",
    "Name": "Denny"
}
```

Note: if the json object has a different Hierarchy please add the necessary steps to access your data

Comment: Please clarify the meaning and implications of the "Note:".  In particular, to whom does "your" refer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To satisfy the search we will use the following:

- `select()`: pick the key that we will be selecting to search explicitly
- `ascii_downcase`: this modifier is helpful for these type of searches where you do not know if the key has a a certain value. This will remove case sensitivity *i.e. `Tom vs tOm vs toM etc`*
- `contains()`: help search for multiple values

`jq 'select( keys[]| ascii_downcase |contains( "pw","password"))'`

**`BONUS:`**

*However another search might be if you want to search the values based on a specific key in more structured sanitized data where the key name is explicitly the same you would be able to search the values by do this ->*

`jq 'select( .Password| ascii_downcase |contains( "pw","password"))'`

Comment: Note that `contains( "pw","password")` will in general return two values, so `"pw is short for password" | select(contains( "pw","password"))` will return two values too.

Answer (score 0):

To sanitize a stream of objects efficiently:

```
with_entries( if .key | ascii_downcase | IN("password", "pw", "pa$$word")
              then .key="Password" 
              else . end)
```

To select efficiently, without sanitizing the results:

```
select( any(keys_unsorted[] | ascii_downcase;
            IN("password", "pw", "pa$$word") ) )
```